# Sublime Text suggest numbers: how to disable it?

Tags: numbers, sublimetext3, autosuggest

These days I'm programming in Python with sublime text and I'm pretty annoyed because I have installed the "SublimeCodeIntel" and "auto-complete", when I write a number, it suggest me some number that I have in the opened files.

there's any way to disable it? I mean, how can I configure the suggestion to NOT appear the ones that start with a number?

Hope someone could help me out! :)

Edit: forget auto-complete. I mean that when I write, for example, "1", sublime suggest me "100" as when I write "p" it suggest me "print". So, Sublime is suggesting me numbers, any way to disable it?

Comment: that's not a Python question, is it?

Comment: my sublime text can do suggestions without any special plugin but it doesn't do it unless i click ctrl+space ... or do you mean it auto completes without suggestions? please be clear.

Comment: @ForceBru, no Python, sorry about it, correct it jus now.

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum sorry about that, I get confused with "auto complete" and "suggestions", I only mean suggestions. An example in the edit.

Comment: that is weird, I have noticed that it does this just now. :) but why is that a problem? Does it suggest these things without even pressing ctrl+space?

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum yes it does! I might have configure it to suggest in any case (is always suggesting)  but I really like it that way. I only was looking for a way to disable number suggestion: names and fuctions suggestions are wonderful and that's why I love Sublime :) But if it can't be done I would change it to "ctrl+space" configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot disable auto complete especially for numericals.
Auto complete can be disabled with the `auto_complete` setting. To disable it, add this line to `Preferences/File Settings - User`:

`"auto_complete": false`

If auto-complete is disabled then, the pop-up can be seen by pressing `Ctrl+Space`, pressing again will select the next option.

Comment: Thank you but it was not what I was looking for. It's my fault, my explanation was really bad, sorry about that but thaks for the help :)